# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08P01]

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, psql

Hello so i am trying to make a search.php file for a website whith PDO and PSQL and i am kind of new to all of this so i get this error

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08P01]: <<Unknown error>>: 7 ERROR: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" requires 1' in C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\Library\search.php:45 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\Library\search.php(45): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM b...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\Library\search.php on line 45
```

and i can't understand why and i have no ideia on what to do... if anyone could help me 
This is the search.php file:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    include '/database/dbc.php';
    //$sesion_type = $_GET['search'];
    $dbc = dbc();

        $search = $_POST['q'];      
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Library</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
            <link rel="icon" href="images/biblioteca1.jpg"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h2>Search</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tfheader">
                    <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="http://localhost:8080/Library/search.php">
                    <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
                    </form>
                <div class="tfclear"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="content">
            <?php
            try
            {
                $quer1 = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search OR author LIKE :search OR genre LIKE :search OR editor LIKE :search";
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            foreach($dbc->query($quer1) as $row )
            {
            ?>
                <td><?php echo($row['title']);?></td>
                <td><?php echo($row['author']);?></td>
                <td><?php echo($row['editor']);?></td>
                <td><?php echo($row['price']);?></td>
                <td><?php echo($row['genre']);?></td>
                <td><?php echo($row['bookid']);?></td>
            <?php
            }   
            ?>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the issue is.  Your query has 1 bound parameter, yet you're not binding any values to it.  Try something like this:

```
try {
    $quer1 = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search OR author LIKE :search OR genre LIKE :search OR editor LIKE :search";
    $sth = $dbc->prepare($quer1);
    $sth->bindParam(':search', $search);
    $sth->execute();

    while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        // ...
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

See also the example in the manual entry for [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).  Notice I also wrapped the entire operation inside of the `try` block.  In your example, the only thing inside of it is the assignment of a string variable, which makes no sense since assigning a string will *never* throw an exception.

You can also bind parameters to your query directly inside of the call to `execute`:

```
$sth->execute(array(':search' => $search));
```

There's also a few different options you can pass in to the [`fetch` method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), and there's a couple of different [fetch methods](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) you could call, so be sure to check those out and use whatever makes the most sense for you.